# Is it considered acceptable to insert the standalone, exclamatory "coïncidence" like this?

Tags: usage, oral, incises

> Chloé et Sarah vivent toutes les deux, **coïncidence**, à Tokyo.
>
> Chloé et Sarah ont toutes les deux, **coïncidence**, 30 ans.

In conversation, I tend to use "coïncidence" parenthetically like this without any preceding word ("*une*"/"*quelle*"). Is this usage (not found in a dictionary entry) considered generally acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this kind of *incise* is common, especially in spoken French, with ***coïncidence*** and other terms like ***surprise***.

It is a shortened version of ***quelle coïncidence !***, ***quelle surprise !***, and is often used ironically.

A similar interjection can be "*[**tada !**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tada)*" (reproducing the sound of a drum roll).

Due to its mainly oral usage, it is difficult to find occurrences of *coïncidence* used that way but here is a similar usage:

> Sur la base d'un vote de 129 entraîneurs, c'est - quelle surprise ! - le Français Zinedine Zidane qui a été couronné.
>   Le Point, 1998

Comment: When you have a preposition, where do you place "coïncidence"? The first one, I take it? "*Chloe et Sarah vivent toutes les deux, coïncidence, à Tokyo.*" or "*Chloe et Sarah vivent toutes les deux à, coïncidence, Tokyo.*"

Comment: The location of these incises is flexible. In addition to both of your valid suggestions, that might also be *Chloé et Sarah, coïncidence, vivent toutes les deux à Tokyo* and *Chloé et Sarah vivent, coïncidence, toutes les deux à Tokyo*.

Comment: I see. Which one is your personal favourite?

Comment: Vivent, coïncidence, toutes les deux...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ok.  Maybe not the way I would put things, I would probably say instead :

*Il se trouve que Chloé at Sarah ont toutes les deux trente ans.*